# Import table from HTML into Matlab

Tags: jquery, html, matlab, urlread, import-table

I am trying to import data from  an html webpage into Matlab. I have come across a function "getTableFromWeb". It looks pretty cool. The problem is when I use a browser for example Firefox I can see the data. But when use this function it can't find any table. Even when I save the html file from browser it only save the code. There is no data. I don't know anything about java html programming. But I read many many relevant questions but I can't find the answer to my problem.
I used Inspect Element in Firefox. It shows in the Debugger, the bootstrap.js and jquery.js and list.html.
I appreciate any help.

> get("http://laaablaaablaaablaaaab is similiar to the url I use to see the data but not identical.

Thanks in advance.

```
<head lang="en">
                     <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>laablaablaab/title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<style>
    .table{
        font-size: 8px;
    }
 </style>
</head>
 <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.html">Register name</a></li>
            <li><a href="guide.html">Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
   </nav>

      <div class="container">
   <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>U L1</th>

        <th>Powerlvl adj max</th>
        <th>VAR Q<small>abs</small></th>
        <th>VAR Q<small>abs</small> lead or lag</th>
               </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <nav>
        <ul class="pager">
            <li class="previous disabled"><a id="pvpg" href="#"><span    aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Older</a>
            </li>
            <li class="next"><a id="nxtpg" href="#">Newer <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
 <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script>
var index = 0;
    var Name = getQueryParameters().name;
  var pages = 50;

  var num = getNumberMeasurements(inverterName);
var nextpager = document.getElementById("nxtpg");
var previouspager = document.getElementById("pvpg");

   getMeasurements(inName, index, pages);

nextpager.onclick = function () {
    if (index >= num / pages)
        return;

    index++;
    getMeasurements(Name, index, pages);
};

previouspager.onclick = function () {
    if (index == 0)
        return;

    index--;
    getMeasurements(Name, index, pages);
};

function handlePagerBtns() {
    var calculated = 0;
    if (num > 0){
        calculated = Math.ceil(num/pages);
    }

    if (index >= calculated) {
        var li = nextpager.parentNode;
        li.className = "next disabled";
    }
    else {
        var li = nextpager.parentNode;
        li.className = "next";
    }

    if (index == 0) {
        var li = previouspager.parentNode;
        li.className = "previous disabled"
    } else {
        var li = previouspager.parentNode;
        li.className = "previous"
    }
}

function getNumberMeasurements(name) {
    var num = 1000;
    return num;
}

function getMeasurements(name, skip, top) {
    handlePagerBtns();

    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
    tbody.innerHTML = "";

    $.get("http://laaablaaablaaablaaaab('" + name + "')/Measurement?$orderby=LogTime+desc&$skip=" + skip*top + "+&$top=" + top, {})
            .done(function (data) {
                data.value.forEach(function (measurement) {
                    var trow = document.createElement("TR");

                    for (var k in measurement) {
                        if (k == "_Name")
                            continue;

                        var tcell = document.createElement("TD");
                        if (k == "Id" || k == "LogTime") {
                            tcell.innerHTML = measurement[k];
                        }
                        else if (k == "ReactivePowerQabsIsLag" || k == "ReactivePowerCosPhiIsLag") {
                            tcell.innerHTML = measurement[k];
                        }
                        else {
                            if (measurement[k] != null)
                                tcell.innerHTML = measurement[k].toFixed(2);
                        }
                        trow.appendChild(tcell);
                    }

                    tbody.appendChild(trow);
                });
            });
}

function getQueryParameters() {
    var queryString = location.search.replace("?", "");
    var params = queryString.split("&");
    var queryParams = {};
    params.forEach(function (parm) {
        var array = parm.split("=");
        queryParams[array[0]] = array[1];
    });

   `
```

Comment: A link to the page would be useful, otherwise impossible to answer.

Comment: http://tekdataacq.elektro.dtu.dk/smartpv/list.html?name=186902N502

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the table is populated by javascript, but your function doesn't evaluate the javascript, it just pulls in the HTML. Check out http://phantomjs.org/ for a common solution written in Javascript. If a solution is built using the Phantom.js command line interface, you could access it from MATLAB via the system() function.

Comment: Can you please provide more information? As I mentioned I am not familiar with java script :(.